# how to change the text size in "showcaseview" library

Tags: android, showcaseview

Is there a way to change text and tile size in showcaseview?
I cant find in the code where the text size is set.

Thanks,
Ilan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a theme, which takes styles for title text appearance and detail text appearance. These can be used to change the text size.

The sample [styles.xml](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/blob/master/sample/src/main/res/values/styles.xml) shows how to customise these attributes. So to change the text size of the title, you'd add a `textSize` attribute to the `CustomTitle`.

Comment: Thanks, in version 5 can i add the swipe gesture? if yes so how?

Comment: you can't currently, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

it's very simple, just need to add into style file as i have mentioned below:

```
<style name="CustomShowcaseTheme2" parent="ShowcaseView">
        <item name="sv_backgroundColor">#90000000</item>
        <item name="sv_showcaseColor">#25467A</item>
        <item name="sv_buttonText">Close</item>
        <item name="sv_titleTextAppearance">@style/CustomTitle2</item>
        <item name="sv_detailTextAppearance">@style/CustomText2</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTitle2" parent="TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Title.Light">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">26sp</item>

    </style>

    <style name="CustomText2" parent="TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Detail.Light">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>

    </style>
```